# PHP - Find if a string contains only whitespaces and nothing else

Tags: php

How do I find out if a string contains ONLY whitespaces and nothing else? The number of such spaces does not matter.

```
if () // $string contains ONLY whitespaces and nothing else   
{
// do something
}
```

Best if can provide a solution that can be generalised to any character:
How do I find if a string contains ONLY some character and nothing else

Comment: Use `preg_match('/^\s+$/',$string)` \s is any whitespace

Answer (score 4):

A non-regex approach could be:

```
if(strlen($string) >= 1 && empty(trim($string))) {
```

`empty(trim($string))` removes all whitespace then checks if the string is empty. `strlen($string) >= 1` confirms the string wasn't empty to start with. If empty strings are also allowed that check can be removed.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest approach:

```
$s && !trim($s)
```

- `$s` will be evaluated to `True` only if it's not empty(contains anything)

---

Testing:

```
$s = " \t \n";
var_dump($s && !trim($s));  // true
```

---

```
$s = "";
var_dump($s && !trim($s));  // false
```

---

***Useful info*** about whitespaces:

```
" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
"\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
```

Comment: probably right (opinion), but OP said 'whitespace and nothing else' whilst your test string does contain something else.

Comment: How about just `$s && !trim($s)`?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, did you know that `\t` and `\n` is in whitespace category?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, that's even shorter, I like that hint

Comment: yes i know, but they are not. OP was not very specific about the why and wherefore of this question, and i am not assuming anything about the background, just being literal about the question. For myself, although some may consider that a bunch of non-whitespace are whitespaces, i dont.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, that's why our answers sometimes should be not just "bare" answers, but a lessons in some extent

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I was thinking it's also worth mentioning that this can also satisfy the OP's "solution that can be generalised to any character" request by using the character mask parameter of `trim`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions:

```
if (preg_match('/^\s*$/', $string)) { 
    // do something
}
```

This expression verifies that the string contains only white-space characters or nothing at all. To exclude empty strings as well, use `/^\s+$/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
if ( preg_match('/\s/',$mystring) )
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The question states *only* whitespaces, your answer checks if a space character is present in the string.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of achieving this: fast&dirty, and true;
Fast wast way is run every char in $string and check it:

```
$is_space=true;
for($i = 0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){
     if($string[$i]!==' '){
          $is_space=false;
     }
}
```

so, here if $is_space is true - then your string contains spaces only;

The second way is regexp, you need to dive a bit deeper http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php,
and you need regexp like that

```
\S+
```

if you can't find smth that is not whitespace - than you have in this string whitespaces only.

Of couse you need to check the string length, and there are many ways to check what you need using regexp.

Comment: `for($i = 0; $i<=strlen($string)-1; $i++){` you don't need the `-1` if you `$i<strlen($string);` (just incase you didn't know)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for checking if a string contains only white spaces.

```
if(preg_match('~\s*~', $string) ) {
       //do something...
  }
```

If you want to check for individual white spaces, then use corresponding escape sequences:

```
if(preg_match('~[\r\n]*~', $string) ) {
       //do something...
  }
```

### You can learn more about regex at [link](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)